# Laravel Query Builder Method addSelect does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I tried to pass data from the database to view. Now I have to write some SQL code in the controller. Is it possible to do more queries from two Query Builder instances? Like my code, obviously, it didn't work; it throws an error.

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::addselect does not exist.

Has anyone a better idea?

```
class StatisticsController extends Controller
{
    public function statistic()
    {
        $right = DB::table('answers')
            ->select('questions.question_title', 'questions.chapters_id',
                DB::raw('count(*) as rightanswers'))
            ->join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.questions_id')
            ->where('answers.is_correct', 1)
            ->groupBy('questions.question_title', 'questions.chapters_id')
            ->get();

        $wrong = DB::table('answers')
            ->select('questions.question_title', 'questions.chapters_id',
                DB::raw('count(*) as wronganswers'))
            ->join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.questions_id')
            ->where('answers.is_correct', 0)
            ->groupBy('questions.question_title', 'questions.chapters_id')
            ->get();

        $data = $right->addselect('questions.title', 'chapters_id',
            'rightanswers/(rightanswers+wronganswers) as rightigeRate')
            ->join('wrong', 'right.questions.title', '=', 'wrong.questions.title')
            ->get();

        return view('/statistics', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

Comment: remove get() from first query .

Comment: now the another error: table wrong was not founded

Comment: Do you have a table named as wrong?

Comment: no, so I make a query builder and do more sql query in this two new query build instance (right and wrong) is it possible?